# Pluralization and nouns

Tags: grammatical-number

I know we would not say `a 3 months period,` but why exactly? Is it because period is noncount? But why is it correct to say `a period of 3 months`

How do you know when to pluralize nouns and when not to? Is there a website that breaks down examples like `period` for me?

Thank you!

Comment: It's actually a `3-month period`. Note the hyphen.

Comment: Attributives are rarely marked as plural (though this is gradually changing).

Comment: It would be better to close this as a duplicate of a question with an accurate answer.